Is |\cos x| acceptable spacing?
If I type $|-1|$ I get | – 1| which is universally deemed bad spacing. It is necessary to substitute \lvert and \rvert to get the right spacing, |–1|.
Likewise, in expressions like $|\cos x|$ and $|\det A|$, LaTeX adds space after the leftmost vertical bar, and many LaTeX guides recommend using \lvert and \rvert here as well. However, I have come across a huge number of papers on the arXiv, including by distinguished professors, that use |, and I have even heard authors argue that the operator is easier to read when it is not so close to the vertical bar. Hence my question: Is there any journal, style guide, etc., that positively favors | over \lvert before a textual math operator, or am I safe to teach my students, coauthors, etc. that it is wrong?


Most distinguished professors write absolutely awful TeX. I know of some who write inner products as <x,y>. Do not get fooled by their scientific brilliance into thinking that they know what they're doing with TeX.

And I've heard people argue that sans text with serif math is great because then it's easier to distinguish between the two. People argue all sorts of crap all the time. Doesn't mean they're right.

Try and look at the sources of the papers on arXiv. You'll find entertaining examples of bizarre code, full of obsolete or deprecated commands. Have a look at https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84gregorio.pdf (shameless advertising): not based on arXiv, but it's not different.

Too bad @egreg doesn't put papers on arXiv for us to look at.

I laughed way too hard reading the comments @Gaussler

Just looking at the image you post should answer your question |  cos x | just looks horribly unbalanced.

Actually, using $|{-1}$ gets the spacing correct---the first example looks bad because TeX is interpreting it as "vertical bar minus 1" there. Ditto for the |\cos x| vs. |{\cos x}| situation.

@karlh the whole point here is that the vertical bar alone is no the proper symbol to use for absolute value. Proper usage need a left and a right version of the delimiters. Vertical bar is neighter. Tex dies exactly what it is suppose to do here.

@daleif I agree, TeX is doing what it is supposed to do (my point exactly), but I will also mention that \lvert and \rvert are not part of TeX OR LaTeX by default (they require amsmath), so...clearly Leslie Lamport and Donald Knuth disagreed with you about the vertical bar not being the "proper" symbol.

@karlh So we're only suppose to use solutions that Knuth or Lamport provided? Good luck with that.

BTW even Knuth used \bigl\vert so he was aware.

@daleif Not at all what I said, and not what I meant. The point is don't call something "improper" if the "proper" way to do it is not even part of the base language. Is it better? Yup, that's why the extension was written. Just to be clear, I use amsmath all the time, pretty much automatically, but I object to saying that someone is writing bad code simply because they did not do it the same way you think they should be doing it.
